# Attempt to prove that for the Poincaré characteristic, $\chi(S)=\chi(S')=$ implies that $S$ is homeomorphic to $S'$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a compact connected surface, then
> $\chi(S)$ assumes one of the values $2,0,-2,...$. Additionally, if
> $S'\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is another compact surface with
> $\chi(S)=\chi(S')$, then $S$ is homeomorphic to $S'$.

which is found in Do Carmo's "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces" in the chapter on the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.

I am attempting to prove this via the Poincaré-Hopf theorem

$\sum_{\{p \in M | X(p)=0\}} ind(X,p)=\chi(M)$

My issue is, that these indices only seem to be invariant under diffeomorphisms and not homeomorphisms, which I need. Is this the wrong attempt?

I'd also be glad for any tips on how to prove the first part of the statement.

Comment: I know nothing of the subject but it may well be relevant to add how you are defining $\chi$

Comment: This is a fact from topology beyond the scope of DoCarmo's text. It is the classification of closed (topological) surfaces.

Comment: Given a triangulation of a surface, $\chi$ is defined as $F-E+V$, where F is the number of triangles, E the number of edges and V the number of vertices. Another statement I need to prove is that $\chi$ in fact does not depend on the triangulation, which makes the definition $\chi(M)$ for a manifold M well defined.

Comment: So, if you have a triangulation on $M$ and a homeomorphism $f\colon M\rightarrow N$, can you "transport" the given triangulation along $f$ to obtain a triangulation of $M$ with the same number of vertices, edges and faces respectively.

Comment: @Thorgott Yes, but how does that help me?

Comment: It implies that $\chi$ is invariant under homeomorphisms, which is what you said you are interested in doing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try if I can use that. But I think I mislabeled the question due to my own currently very limited understanding of the subject. What I want to prove is the statement from Do Carmo's book. I think the current title fits better.

Comment: That is something you will in all likelihood not succeed in proving. As Ted mentions, it is a rather non-trivial theorem.

Comment: Thanks, that's unfortunate.